# What is the best way to write to several logs that are continuously being updated?

Tags: javascript, file, file-io, air

Working on an irc client in Adobe AIR in JavaScript, and thinking about logging. Each channel would have its own log file. I wouldn't keep all of the logs open while the app was running would I? I'd log every few minutes? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not to keep all the log files open.  I would not expect any other apps to write to the logs, at least while your client is open.  I also would not try (at least at first) to implement your own buffering.  Just write lines as they come and let the OS and runtime do the buffering.

Comment: people could be in like 30 ore more channels at a time. That would be 30 connections to files. Even given this, it's ok to keep the files open?

Comment: 30 open file handles is nothing on a modern machine.  On my GNU/Linux machine, the system-wide limit is 205017.